# Stone-Weierstrass: Lattice

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lattice-orders

*This is just a prework.*

Given a compact domain.

Regard the function space:
$$\mathcal{C}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}):=\{f:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}:f\text{ continuous}\}$$

Clearly it is an algebra:
$$f+g\in\mathcal{C}(\Omega,\mathbb{R})\quad\lambda f\in\mathcal{C}(\Omega,\mathbb{R})$$

How to see that it is a lattice?

Comment: why is this a lattice? it is not a crystal

Comment: @MathNewb: Haha ^^ *(Or, was your question serious?)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer is community wiki.*

The meet and join can be rewritten as:
$$f\wedge g=\frac12\{(f+g)-|f-g|\}\quad f\vee g=\frac12\{(f+g)+|f-g|\}$$
*(Note that addition, multiplication and modulus are continuous.)*

Comment: The point being that **pointwise** max and min of continuous functions are continuous functions, and these are the least upper bound and greatest lower bound in terms of the partial order.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: And that in turn is a consequence of the continuity of addition, multiplication and modulus within the reals... ;)

Comment: You certainly can do it that way, but it's just as easy to do directly.  $|\max(f(x),g(x)) - \max(f(y),g(y))| \le \max(|f(x) - f(y)|,|g(x)-g(y)|)$.